# Booting to Ubuntu 20.10 is unreliable - screen flash

Tags: nvidia, inspiron, 20.10

I have a Dell Inspiron 7779, dual booting with Ubuntu 20.10 and Windows Ten.

I had Ubuntu 20.04 on it before upgrading to Groovy on its release a month ago. An issue had been creeping in on Focal, and has gotten worse since upgrading.

When I boot into Ubuntu, the boot screen, with the Dell logo appears, then there's a screen flash but before the login screen appears, the screen goes black, then a dark grey colour - that's only really noticeable in a dark room - black, grey, black, grey, etc until the login screen appears.
After entering my username and password, this repeats for about 20 seconds until my home screen appears. Sometimes this is longer, up to a minute, and sometimes I have to restart the machine from the power button. I have noticed that pressing the return key can sometimes make this complete faster.

When I suspend the machine, this same process is repeated, but the login screen only appears
about one in every eight times I try to bring it back, usually I have to restart.

For comparison, booting into Windows, and suspending/restoring the system works every time.

Can you help with this?

Comment: can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by switching to the X.org drivers and selecting "Ubuntu on Wayland" at the login screen.
No screen flash on boot or login, and the machine itself is running quieter as well!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding "nomodeset" in the grub config menu.
which suggested on dell website: (I'd recommend 'partII' method)

> [https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-au/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en>](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-au/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en%3E)?

Alternatively, if you cant edit cause by "screen flash"; boot up using "ubuntu live cd" then edit your "/root/grub/grub.cfg" (which is what "partI" is doing)
you will need to update under the "linux_gfx_mode" section to add "nomodeset" as per instruction "partI".